# Is there a way to determine whether an "Enter" keypress originated from an Angular Material autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I am using an [Angular Material Autocomplete](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview) control as a search bar.  The search bar behaves in a fairly typical way - the user types their query, presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and the search is triggered.

However, if the user selects a suggestion from the autocomplete (for example, "beaton" or "beck" in the image below), I'd like the search **not** to be triggered.

[image: An Angular Material Autocomplete control]

How can I determine whether the <kbd>Enter</kbd> keypress was the result of the user selecting an autocomplete suggestion or if it was the user triggering a search?

Both cases cause my `onSearchKeydown` function to be called:

```
// my.controller.ts 
public async onSearchKeydown($event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if ($event.which === Key.Enter) {
        const results = await this.search(this.query);
    }
}
```

Here's the relevant portion of my component's HTML:

```
<!-- my.component.html -->
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput
           autofocus
           [(ngModel)]="query"
           (keydown)="onSearchKeydown($event)"
           [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let s of suggestions">
            <span>{{s.value}}</span>
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if any of the autocomplete suggestions has the mat-active class. If yes, than it was triggered by choosing an autocomplete suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You only really need to know if the "query" value is a selectable option. And you can do that in the onSearchKeydown function before calling the search. Something like:

```
public async onSearchKeydown($event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if ($event.which === Key.Enter) {
        if (!this.suggestions.some(item => {
            return item.value === this.query;
        })) {
            const results = await this.search(this.query);
        }
    }
}
```

You might also be able to use a trick. If your option value is a class or object, you can check whether or not the model value is the same as opposed to a string which would indicate typed text:

```
public async onSearchKeydown($event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if ($event.which === Key.Enter) {
        if (typeof this.query == 'string') {
            const results = await this.search(this.query);
        }
    }
}

suggestions = [
   { value: 'Apple' },
   { value: 'Banana' },
   { value: 'Cherry' }
];

displaySuggestion(suggestion) {
    return suggestion ? suggestion.value : '';
}

<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displaySuggestion">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let s of suggestions" [value]="s">
        <span>{{s.value}}</span>
    </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

Also - if you bind to `(keyup.enter)` instead of `(keydown)` you don't have to check the key.